# Update em uma coluna usando mais de um retorno

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

Eu tenho que atualizar um determinado campo de uma tabela subtraindo dele os valores retornados de um select em outra tabela. O problema que estou enfrentando é que como o select retorna mais de um valor e tenho que ir subtraindo valor por valor, para poder comparar se o valor atual é menor que o valor da consulta, não sei como fazer isso. O que eu fiz da erro dizendo que o resultado tem mais de um valor e não pode executar.

```
update Produto2 set valor = case when (select p.valor from Produto p where p.clienteId = clienteId) < valor then 
valor - (select p.valor from Produto p where p.id = produtoId) else
valor - 0 end;
```

E além disso no final teria q atualizar a segunda tabela dizendo quais dados que foram usados, mas n sei como guardar os ids que foram atualizados.

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/language-elements/while-transact-sql   leia sobre cursores, seguem exemplos.

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que, na tabela produto só há um valor para cada cliente e produto, e que você precisa atualizar produto2, subtraindo o valor de produto caso ele seja menor.

> Acho que pode simplificar essa query e resolver da seguinte forma:

```
update produto2 set 
    valor = valor - coalesce((select 
                                  p.valor 
                              from produto p 
                              where p.clienteId = clienteId 
                              and p.id = produtoId 
                              and p.valor < valor),0);
```

Comment: O problema é que na tabela produto pode ter mais de um valor, é justamente nessa parte que eu não consigo, pq a busca na tabela produto retorna mais de um valor e n sei como ir diminuindo cada um enquanto ainda pode.

Comment: Qual o limite do "ainda pode" ?

Comment: Coloque a estrutura das tabelas por favor

Comment: enquanto valor do produto2 for maior que o valor do produto 1

Comment: é justamente ai que não sei como fazer pra ir subtraindo linha por linha do select em produto, no valor do produto2 atual.

Comment: Qual seria a forma mais simples pra poder fazer essa subtração? já tentei de todas as formas que eu sei e não vai.

Comment: @Loid reproduz seu ambiente no sqlfiddle.com por favor

Answer (score 0):

Faz o Update com o FROM, desta forma:

MySQL:

```
create table produto(clientid integer, valor integer);
create table produto2(clientid integer, valor integer);
insert into produto(clientid , valor) values(1, 100);
insert into produto(clientid , valor) values(2, 200);
insert into produto2(clientid , valor) values(1, 100);
insert into produto2(clientid , valor) values(2, 400);
update produto2 inner join produto on produto.clientid = produto2.clientid set produto2.valor = produto2.valor - produto.valor where produto.valor < produto2.valor;

select * from produto2;
```

SQL Server:

```
UPDATE PRODUTO2
SET VALOR = (PRODUTO2.VALOR - P.VALOR)
FROM PRODUTO2
INNER JOIN PRODUTO P (NOLOCK) ON
   P.CLIENTID = PRODUTO2.CLIENTEID
WHERE P.VALOR < PRODUTO2.VALOR
```

Como saber quais registros serão atualizados? Basta trocar por select:

```
SELECT
PRODUTO2.CLIENTID, PRODUTO2.VALOR, P.VALOR  
FROM PRODUTO2
INNER JOIN PRODUTO P (NOLOCK) ON
   P.CLIENTID = PRODUTO2.CLIENTEID
WHERE P.VALOR < PRODUTO2.VALOR
```

Esta é uma das formas mais seguras de se realizar um UPDATE.

`*Atenção*: A mesma tabela que esta no FROM, deverá estar no UPDATE, isto se aplica caso também seja aplicado ALIAS.`

Exemplos corretos:

```
• UPDATE PRODUTO SET VALOR = 1000 FROM PRODUTO WHERE PRODUTO.ID = 3
• UPDATE P SET VALOR = 1000 FROM PRODUTO P WHERE P.ID = 3
```

Exemplo INCORRETO:

```
• UPDATE PRODUTO FROM PRODUTO P WHERE P.ID = 3
```

O SQL permitirá atualizar de forma errada? Sim. Isto poderá causar inconsistência no banco de dados se tiver outros relacionamentos? Sim. Há informações mais detalhadas sobre estas inconsistências da cláusula UPDATE na documentação do banco de dados.